# Eliminar elementos por su contenido de texto JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Quiero eliminar ciertos elementos `<th>` que contengan el texto completo "ABC".

Por ejemplo:

```
<th class="text-center" width="45">ABC</th>
```

¿Cómo se hace sin jQuery solo usando JavaScript?

Comment: Busca todos los th y luego mira uno a uno ti el texto interno es el que buscas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debemos primero seleccionar todos los elementos `th` usando el método de JS `getElementsByTagName()`

```
var elementosTH = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
```

este método devolverá una colección de todos los elementos `th` del documento HTML.

ahora debemos usar un ciclo para acceder a cada uno de los elementos y averiguar si contiene el texto `'ABC'`

usaremos el ciclo `for`, y la propiedad `textContent` de cada elemento.

```
for (var indice = 0; indice < elementosTH.length; indice++) {

    var texto = elementosTH[indice].textContent;

    if (texto === "ABC") {
        // eliminar elemento
    }
}
```

por último vamos a eliminar los elementos con el texto `ABC`

`elementosTH[indice].parentNode.removeChild(elementosTH[indice])`

Nuestro código quedaría de la siguiente manera

```
var elementosTH = document.getElementsByTagName('th');

for (var indice = 0; indice < elementosTH.length; indice++) {

    var texto = elementosTH[indice].textContent;

    if (texto === "ABC") {
        elementosTH[indice].parentNode.removeChild(elementosTH[indice]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un código para hacerlo. Esta comentado para que le entiendas. Saludos!

```js
function deleteTh(param){
  // Seleccionamos todaslas etiquetas <th>
  var ths = document.querySelectorAll("th");
  // "ths" es un array que contiene todas las etiquetas.
  // ahora debemos reccorrer dicho array y verificar el contenido de cada uno
  ths.forEach(function(item, index, object) {
    if (item.textContent === param) {
      //Si el contenido coincide con el parametro, borra dicha etiqueta.
      ths[index].parentNode.removeChild(ths[index]);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
th {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>ABC</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button onclick="deleteTh('ABC')">Eliminr TH</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
function deleteElement(){
    /* Obtenemos el valor del input y lo guardamos en la variable */
    var inputValue = document.getElementById('delete').value;

    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('td'); // Buscamos todos los elementos td

 for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
     var row = rows[i];
            /* Comprobamos el texto de cada elemento */
            if( 
                row.textContent.toLowerCase()
                .indexOf( inputValue.toLowerCase().trim() ) > -1 
              )
              {
                  /* Llamamos al removedor con el elemento a remover */
           removeElement( row );
              }
 }
}

/* Removedor de elementos */
function removeElement( el ) {
 el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
```

```css
td {
  margin:5px;
  padding:15px;
  background:#f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>ABC</td>
   <td>DEF</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>GHI</td>
   <td>123</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<br>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="delete">
  <input type="submit" value="Eliminar" onclick="deleteElement(); return false;">
</form>
```

Para obtener el valor del input uso `document.getElementById('delete').value;`.

Para obtener todos los th uso `document.getElementById('delete').value;`

Para saber si el texto introducido en el input esta en un elemento uso `row.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf( inputValue.toLowerCase().trim() ) > -1`

Obtengo el texto dentro del th con `row.textContent` y lo convierto en minúsculas con `toLowerCase()` y hago la busqueda con `.indexOf( value )` donde `value` es el valor del input (`inputValue`) convertido en minuscula `inputValue.toLowerCase()` y elimina espacios en blanco con `.trim()`

Si existe resultados me arroja el numero de la posición, en cambio si no hay, devuelve -1. Por eso es que coloco el `> -1` en el `if`

Si existen resultados pasamos el elemento `row`, que es el elemento especifico con la id correspondiente de los elementos `rows` que son todos los `<th>`, a la función `removeElement( el )` que se encarga de remover el elemento pasado en el parametro `el`.

De esta manera podemos eliminar elementos que en su contenido tengo, sin importar la posición, el texto escrito en el input.

Por ejemplo si tenemos un `th` con texto `123` y en el input eliminamos con el numero `2` si eliminará el `th`

Espero haber respondido correctamente. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por todo!